# Calling and consuming a JBoss Web Service from JavaScript (AJAX)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-services, jboss

I am fiddling around with JBOSS's Web Services, and I have created the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/IM/TestService?wsdl
```

Now I need to access Web Methods from that Web Service from JavaScript.

Say I have a web method named `foo` in `TestService`, how do I make an ajax call to it?

I tried accessing the method via `http://127.0.0.1:8080/IM/TestService/foo`, but I'm getting an HTTP Status 404.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the server using SoapUI or curl or the Firefox Poster plugin? If you can't connect with them then you've got JBOSS configured badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following JavaScript that will allow me to call the Web Methods from the JBoss Web Service.

**Dependencies**

- [jQuery](http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif)
- [XML Objectifier](http://www.terracoder.com/index.php/xml-objectifier)
- [jQuery Soap Client](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient) (depends on jQuery and XML Objectifier)

---

```
var WS = function (url, ns, nsName) {
    return function (method, parameters, callback) {
        var i, j, para, soapBody = new SOAPObject(method), sr, response;
        soapBody.ns = {
            name: nsName,
            uri: ns
        };
        if (typeof parameters === "function") {
            callback = parameters;
        } else if (parameters && parameters.length) {
            for (i = 0, j = parameters.length; i < j; ++i) {
                para = parameters[i];
                soapBody.appendChild(new SOAPObject(para.name)).val(para.value);
            }
        }
        sr = new SOAPRequest(method, soapBody);
        SOAPClient.Proxy = url;
        SOAPClient.SendRequest(sr, function (r) {
            response = r.Body[0][method + "Response"][0]["return"][0]["Text"];
            if (callback) {
                callback.call(sr, response);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
var ws = WS("http://127.0.0.1:8080/IM/TestService", "http://wservices/", "ns2");

ws("foo", [{name: "name", value:"dreas"}], function (r) {
    console.log(r);
});
```

Disclaimer: *This is still very much untested, so it can still blow up your computer*